# Always says the input is alphanumeric except when i submits nothing

Tags: php

Here is a code. Whenever I submits anything the output says it's alphanumeric help me to get out of here.

```
<?php

$string ="$_POST[in]";

if(ctype_alnum($string)) 
{
echo "'{$string}' is alphanumeric!";
} else {
echo "'{$string}' is NOT alphanumeric!";
}

?>
<form action="alphanum.php" method="post">
<h1>Make Input:<input name="in"><span><input type="submit" value="Check"></span></h1>
</form>
```

Comment: What kind of input have you tested with?

Comment: `$string =$_POST['in]';`

Comment: I made input helloworld

Comment: How is "helloworld" *not* alphanumeric and what do you expect instead?!

Comment: I don't think that helloworld consists any letter 0-9 my aim is to say it's an alphanumeric when I enter hello23 and not alphanumeric when i enter hellgg

Comment: Problem solved please follow the following url: http://devbro.in/2014/05/20/check-input-alphabet-separately-php/

Comment: Well, that's not what this function does. It checks if all characters in the string are either alphabetical or numeric, which is the common definition of "alphanumeric". It does not mean that there have to be numbers and letters.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `ctype_alpha`, this checks if the text enterd is alphabet only or it has numbers where as, `ctype_alnum` checks for both numbers and alphabets and considers both as alphanumeric

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['in'])) {
    $string =$_POST['in']; // validate / sanitize here

    //$string = "(*&";
    if(ctype_alpha($string))
    {
        echo "'{$string}' is NOT alphanumeric!";
    } else {
        echo "'{$string}' is alphanumeric!";
    }
}


?>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <h1>Make Input:<input name="in"><span><input type="submit" value="Check" name="check"></span></h1>
</form>
```